# Nodejs send multiple results with the same res.json

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I have a large nodejs controller doing a lot of mongodb work, and I want it to send several different json results back to caller (my angular controller).

```
findAllBanks
    .then(findAllReceipts)
    .then(findAllTransactions)
    .then(res.json({error:false, bankArray + receiptsArray + transactionArray}))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("getbankAccountReport ERR: " + err);
        res.json({error:true,err})
    })
```

Unfortunately all 3 result arrays are different.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: So your question is how to merge the `bankArray` , `receiptArray` and `transactionArray` ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send these arrays as follows

```
res.json({error:false, "bank":bankArray, "receipt":receiptsArray, "transaction":transactionArray})
```

It is just standard `json` , and you can have your own keys instead of `bank` , `receipt` and `transaction`

Comment: that worked! - I can always split it again in Angular.  Thanks :)

Comment: I always do @Santosh :-)